# How to parse magento object

Tags: php, magento

I would like to show some text under specific category. For that I would like to get category id. I printed category array in top.phtml(custom design) as shown below;

```
<?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>

 print_r($_category);
```

The above print_r gives result as below.How can I parse the below object to get  entity_id(here its value is 1013) or name(here it is 'winning looks').

```
Mage_Catalog_Model_Category Object
(
[_eventPrefix:protected] => catalog_category
[_eventObject:protected] => category
[_cacheTag:protected] => catalog_category
[_useFlatResource:protected] => 1
[_designAttributes:Mage_Catalog_Model_Category:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => custom_design
        [1] => custom_design_from
        [2] => custom_design_to
        [3] => page_layout
        [4] => custom_layout_update
        [5] => custom_apply_to_products
    )

[_treeModel:protected] => 
[_defaultValues:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[_storeValuesFlags:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[_lockedAttributes:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[_isDeleteable:protected] => 1
[_isReadonly:protected] => 
[_resourceName:protected] => catalog/category_flat
[_resource:protected] => 
[_resourceCollectionName:protected] => catalog/category_flat_collection
[_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1
[_isObjectNew:protected] => 
[_data:protected] => Array
    (
        [entity_id] => 1013
        [name] => Winning Looks
        [path] => 1/2/1013
        [is_active] => 1
        [is_anchor] => 1
        [request_path] => winning-looks.html
        [id] => 1013
    )

[_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1
[_origData:protected] => 
[_idFieldName:protected] => entity_id
[_isDeleted:protected] => 
[_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
    (
    )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get with  `<?php echo $category->getEntityId()?>`

```
<?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): 

   print_r($_category);
   echo $_category->getEntityId()

   endforeach;
?>
```

hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($_category->getId() == 1013){ //or $_category->getEntityId();
   //your magic code here
}
```

Comment: //or $_category->getEntitId(); should be //or $_category->getEntityId();, pls don't mind